# I need help for creating a method to delete a particular item in an 'n' depth associative array by passing the array as reference

Tags: php

The reason for pass by reference is that, after deleting that element we need that array for further processing. I would prefer answers from php developers.

### Array content in Json structure

```
"rootnode":
{
    "node1":
    {
        "node2":
        {
            "subNode1":
            {
                "subNode1_1":
                {
                    "element1":"value1",
                    "element2":"value2",
                    "element3":"value3",
                    "element4":"value4"
                }
                "element1":"value1",
                "element2":"value2",
                "element3":"value3",
                "element4":"value4"
            }

            "subNode2":
            {
                "element1":"value1",
                "element2":"value2",
                "element3":"value3",
                "element4":"value4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Code

```
class NodeClass
{
    //$baseNodeArray is multidimensional associative array which has complete contents.
    //$nodePathArray array is 1 dimensional array and has path to the node item that we want to delete. For example rootnode->node1->node2->subNode1->subNode1_1
    //nodeItemToDelete is the node item that we should delete. For example element3 in the path rootnode->node1->node2->subNode1->subNode1_1->element3
    $this->deleteElement($baseNode, $nodePath, "element3");
}

deleteElement(&$baseNodeArray, $nodePathArray, $nodeItemToDelete)
{
    //..
}
```

Comment: You can also return the array, of course, instead of passing it as reference. Your example for `$nodePathArray` is this: `rootnode->node1->node2->subNode1->subNode1_1`, and your comment says it's a one-dimensional array. How is that an array? And: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The sample code that I have given is by assuming we have 2 arrays, one array contains whole content and the other contains node path.